# Converting multiple PDF files into separate text files in a folder in R

Tags: r, text, type-conversion

I'm new to R and very new to Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to read multiple PDF files into different text files. Because of the PDF, I have to convert them into PNG first. Then I want to extract the text from each PNG from the same PDF into a text file.

So the output would look like:
text_file_1: pdf1_png1, pdf1_png2, ...
text_file_2: pdf2_png1, pdf2_png2, ...

The code I have so far is:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf", full.names=TRUE)
 for (i in files) {
  for (j in i) {
     pngfile_i <- pdftools::pdf_convert(i, dpi = 600)
     text_i <- tesseract::ocr(pngfile_1)
     filename <- paste(i,".txt",sep = "")
     capture.output(text_i, filename, append = TRUE)
    }
  }
```

But honestly, I'm not sure if I need separate text files. If I can have an output of a table with the pdf title and then the text, that would solve the problem too.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: greetings. it will be helpful for readers if you can explain what your sample code does (or doesn't do) relative to your goals.

Comment: You could extract the text of the PDF with pdftools::pdf_text and write the text to a "txt file" with the R function writeLines. I feel this would be a simpler approach

Answer (score 0):

You can consider an approach like this :

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf", full.names=TRUE)
nb_Files <- length(files)
list_Text <- list()
for(i in 1 : nb_Files) 
{
     list_Text[[i]] <- pdftools::pdf_text(files[i])
     file_Name <- paste0("file", i, ".txt")
     con <- file(file_Name)
     writeLines(list_Text[[i]], con = con)
}
```